# JSON to CSV with python

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I am doing a data analysis project and I need to convert the files from `JSON` to `CSV`.

I started learning python just recently. Here is my code for `json to csv(json2csv.py)`.

It works with specified file defined in json2csv.py.

I want to modify it with run json2csv.py "RFC.json" in the terminal.

**How can I modify this?**

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JDQr.png)

Comment: Copy paste your code if you want to share it. Do not post screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    json_raw_data = json.load(f)
```

now when you type

> python json2csv.py "RFC.json"

It will assign RFC.json to sys.argv[1]

Comment: thanks a lot. it is my fist time to post. It looks weird as i paste code directly.

Comment: No problem. If my answer solved your issue, please mark it as correct and upvote. Cheers!